# the other side of the road

Tags: meaning

In this picture "the other side of the road" is number "1" or number "2"?
[image]

it was because of a picture that I saw in an Elementary vocabulary book. (ENGLISH VOCABULARY IN USE, Third Edition, Elementary, p. 64).

[image]

Comment: It's number one. The other side of the street is the side in front of you or in front of something you are talking about. 2) is on the **same side of the street** as you, but down/up three blocks from you.

Comment: If it helps to understand, on most streets, traffic flows in opposite directions on each *side* of the street, so the opposite side would be *across* the street.

Comment: 2 is perhaps "the other end of the road".

Comment: Can you explain your doubt about this question?  Why do you think both might be possible

Comment: @JamesK Yes, it was because of a picture that I saw in an Elementary vocabulary book. (ENGLISH VOCABULARY IN USE, Third Edition, Elementary, p. 64). Sinc I can not add the picture here, I'll add it in a new answer.

Comment: I've added it to the question.  Remember you can always edit your question to add information.  The actual problem you have might be a little different from the question you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#1. The "other side of the street" is across the street from where you are standing.

You might say that #2 is "the other side of Park Street" from you. But people just don't normally describe things that way. You'd have to be standing on Park Street to talk about "the other side of Park Street", not three blocks away.

Answer (score 1):

Number 1 is on the other side of the road, (where *the* road is understood to be the High Street.) The Tourist information office is also on the other side of the road, but not directly opposite.

Number 2 is on the same side of the road.

Looking at the other picture, it isn't very clear where you are starting from.  The "you are here" seems to be pointing to the middle of the road.  "Go left" doesn't make sense.  But if you walk up the left side of the High Street you will come to the bus station, and then the Bank is indeed on the other side of the road.